# Building a Web Framework

Tags: ruby, frameworks

I was looking for some advice on building a Web Framework. I'd like to build a custom framework built on Ruby (but not Rails) focused on security and usability. Can someone point me toward resources for building such a Framework?

Comment: If you're asking questions like this, why aren't you just using a preexisting one?

Comment: I am using a preexisting one. I want to know how they work, and I want to build my own

Comment: This is a pretty general question. Try looking into existing frameworks first and getting an idea of how they work. Perhaps you can improve upon them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating a web framework (if you don't want to handle all of the http stuff) i'd look into [rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/)

for example:

```
class App
  def call
    [200, {"Content-type:" => "text/html"}, ["Hello"]]
  end
end

# config.ru

run App.new
```

Comment: That will make your life at lot easier.. I wrote a small web framework using rack in 70 lines (really badly written)

Comment: yea, I really like Rails, but I have no need for many of the bloated features. Instead of removing them and hunting down in a fairly undocumented framework (until recently), I'd prefer to make something much more lightweight that requires actual coding knowledge (vs. Rails), but is super fast and easy-to-use.

Comment: have you had a look at sinatra?

Answer (score 3):

I'm also trying to build a Ruby web framework from scratch. I recently came across this book: http://rebuilding-rails.com which goes through creating a ruby web framework from scratch. I haven't read it yet, but it looks like a great resource.

Comment: Thank you. that's fantastic. Otherwise, I have tried to investigate rack (the base FM for sinatra and rails) and a lot of things has appeared to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of Ruby Frameworks. 
http://www.thepixelart.com/ruby-frameworks-what-are-they-and-why-should-you-choose-one-which-one/

You could get ideas/ inspiration from their architectures.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot possibly build a viable framework from scratch, more so build one focused on usability.

It has to grow organically and be first based on your own needs and follow your own requirements. Only after having built several applications you can extract common portions into a separate framework, refining and polishing the details.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that you can't build a viable FM from scratch. I have a focus - usability and security.

Comment: I also think that it's completely possible. Especially with Ruby where you have a lot of gems (and Rack) which handle a lot of the boilerplate code.